# Send event from custom class that implements observable outside call method using rxjava

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, observable

I have some listeners on a volley request that extends Observable.OnSubscribe and i want to emit a message using rxjava when those methods are reached. Basically i have:

```
public class CallListener implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>{

  Boolean success;

  public void onSucess() {
    success = true;
    // need to call call()
  }

  public void onError() {
     success = false;
     // need to call call()
  }

  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
     // How can i call this method from onSuccess and onError ?
     subscriber.onNext(success);
     subscriber.onCompleted();
  }


}
```

How can i call call() method from onSuccess and onError? My goal here is to use an observer to chain the callListeners which are basically UI controllers for each request (create loadings, provide error handling, save json) without having to create a third class just to make callListener an observable (i want to emit messages direct from CallListener). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely understanding your use case.  But if you are simply trying to call onNext and onComplete methods from success/failure methods you can likely just hold onto the subscription reference and use it as needed.

```
  public class CallListener implements Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>{

  Boolean success;
  Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber;

  public void onSuccess() {
    success = true;
    // need to call callOnNext()
    callOnNext();
  }

  public void onError() {
     success = false;
     // need to call callOnNext()
     callOnNext();
  }

  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
     this.subscriber = subscriber;
  }

  private void callOnNext(){
      if(subscriber != null && !subscriber.isUnsubscribed()){
          subscriber.onNext(success);
          subscriber.onCompleted();
          subscriber = null;
      }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you add an example of registering an observer to this class?